# `find -path` explained

Tags: find

The `find` command provides the option `-path`. I understand that one has to define where to start looking [commonly known as "path"]. Trying to figure out what it is used for, I found many examples using `find -path -prune` to exclude some paths.

**Question**: An explanation what `find -path` does; what this option is used for.

Please note: It seems crystal clear to me, but then doesn't work as I guessed it would. I worked through the `man` and the `info` pages, but I don't get the full meaning of this option.

**EDIT** As I understand it: `find /some/path -name stuff` should start looking for "stuff", starting in the directory `path` which is a subdirectory of `some`. Works. But then, what does the `-path` option define?
Definitions including sentences like

> do not treat `/` or `.` specially

doesn't help much and are even more confusing.

Comment: Don't you think that "It seems crystal clear, but then doesn't work as I guessed it would" is worth an example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-path` does not (re)define the start path. It refers to the combination of the start path and the relative path of the currently examined object.

You may by this e.g. find all files within a subdirectory `src` no matter on which level.

"do not treat / or . specially" means that `*` can match both file names including the extension and into subdirectories: `[...]/file*` would match both `/file.txt` and `/files/foo.bar`

Comment: Hi, I have some questions about your reply http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200344/further-questions-about-path-for-find?noredirect=1#comment337661_200344. Thanks if you can take a look.

Answer (score 22):

It's used for globbing the *entire* current path. If you have `-path '*bin/*rch'` and you're currently looking at `/sbin/ausearch` then it will match.