# Further questions about -path for find

Tags: find

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81379/674

1. > `-path` does not (re)define the start path. It refers to the
   >   combination of the start path and the relative path of the currently
   >   examined object.

   - Does "start path" mean the argument `path` to `find`?:

     ```
     find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
     ```
   - What does "combination of the start path and the relative path of the currently examined object" mean?
2. > You may by this e.g. find all files within a subdirectory `src` no
   >   matter on which level.

   How is 'find all files within a subdirectory `src` no matter on
   which level" done?
3. > "do not treat / or . specially" means that `*` can match both file
   >   names including the extension and into subdirectories: `[...]/file*`
   >   would match both `/file.txt` and `/files/foo.bar`

   "do not treat / or . specially" doesn't mention `*`, so does "do not
   treat / or . specially" only apply to `*`?

Comment: Your question refers to somebody's wording of an answer in a different thread.  Perhaps you should ask for clarification in a comment?

Comment: The author hasn't logged in for a while.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, "start path" means one of the directory names that appear
   near the beginning of the `find` command,
   after the options but before the expression. 
   I interpret the question that you linked to as suggesting that that OP
   was confused about the difference between

   ```
   find /etc ...
   ```

   and

   ```
   find -path /etc ...
   ```

   ---

   - > "It refers to the combination of the start path
     > and the relative path of the currently examined object."

     I guess the author of that answer is imagining that
     you have a directory called `tools/crowbar`,
     which contains files `drink`, `food`, `foolishness`, and `wisdom`. 
     If you say

     ```
     find tools/crowbar -path "*bar/foo*"
     ```

     it will find `tools/crowbar/food`
     and `tools/crowbar/foolishness`, but not the other two.
2. I agree with lcd047. 
   To put it another way, if you have a directory structure like

   ```
   .
   ├───cat
   │   ├───dog
   │   │   └───kennel
   │   └───tac
   │       └───src
   ├───dest
   ├───original
   │   ├───recipe
   │   └───src
   └───src
   ```

   then

   ```
   find . -path "*/src/*"
   ```

   will find things in all three `src` folders
   (and all subdirectories thereof)
   without reporting things in `cat`, `cat/dog`, `cat/dog/kennel`,
   `cat/tac`, `dest`, `original`, or `original/recipe`.
3. It helps to read entire paragraphs,
   and not just cherry-pick sentence fragments
   and expect them to make sense in isolation. 
   The discussion of the `-path` test
   in [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says,

   > `-path pattern`
   >
   >   File name matches shell pattern
   >   *pattern*
   >   . 
   >   The metacharacters do not treat ‘
   >   `/`
   >   ’
   >   or ‘
   >   `.`
   >   ’ specially; so, for example,
   >       ```
   >       find . -path "./sr*sc"
   >       ```
   >   will print an entry for a directory called ‘`./src/misc`’
   >   (if one exists).  ...

   OK, when you see "file name", "shell pattern",
   and "metacharacters" all on the same line,
   you’re expected to think of the shell’s pattern matching /
   pathname expansion, which has special pattern characters
   **`*`**, **`?`**, and **`[`**...**`]`**. 
   ("Metacharacter" is basically a $10 word for "special character".) 
   And then it goes and shows you an example with a `*` in it! 
   So you should be able to figure out what it’s talking about.

   So, what is it saying? 
   Look at the example: `sr*sc` matches `src/misc`.
   This is a difference from pathname expansion in the shell,
   where you would generally need to use
   something like `sr*/*sc` to match `src/misc`. 
   And, no, this doesn’t apply only to `*`;
   `-path "sr????sc"` and `-path "sr[cim/][cim/][cim/][cim/]sc"`
   work the same way.

   And what they don’t bother to mention is that `-path "*sr*sc"`
   will match not only `src/misc` but also `.src/misc` and `src/.misc`;
   even though `*sr*/*sc` generally won’t match those (in the shell)
   because, in the shell’s pathname expansion,
   `*` generally doesn’t match names that begin with **`.`**.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid confusion you should probably think of the prototype for `find(1)` like this:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [dir...] [expression]
```

`find(1)` finds files in `dir`.  `expression` is a logical expression formed of tests that are applied to the files found.  `-path`, `-name`, `-type` are examples of such tests.

1. above basically says `-path` doesn't set `dir`, but it's argument is taken as relative to `dir`.
2. says `-path '*src*'` matches both `./src/foo/bar/test.c` and `./foo/src/bar/test.c`, but not `./foo/bar/test.c`.
3. says `*` is a wildcard, and it matches across directories.  It also says you shouldn't confuse it with `*` from the DOS / Windows world, where you need to write `*.*` to match files with "extensions".

Or at least this is my understanding of it.