# Explain find's -path and -prune options

Tags: find

I have a simple script that I understand most of, it's the find command that's unclear. I've got a lot of documentation but it's not serving to make it much clearer. My thought is that it is working like a for-loop, the currently found file is swapped in for {} and copied to $HOME/$dir_name, but how does the search with *-path* and *-prune -o* work? It's annoying to have such specific and relevant documentation and still not know what's going on.

```
#!/bin/bash
# The files will be search on from the user's home
# directory and can only be backed up to a directory
# within $HOME

read -p "Which file types do you want to backup " file_suffix
read -p "Which directory do you want to backup to " dir_name

# The next lines creates the directory if it does not exist
test -d $HOME/$dir_name || mkdir -m 700 $HOME/$dir_name

# The find command will copy files that match the
# search criteria ie .sh . The -path, -prune and -o
# options are to exclude the backdirectory from the
# backup.
find $HOME -path $HOME/$dir_name -prune -o \
-name "*$file_suffix" -exec cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/ \;
exit 0
```

This is just the documentation that I know I should be able to figure this out from.

> -path pattern
>
> File  name  matches  shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do not treat */* or *.*
>   specially; so, for example,
>   find . -path "./sr*sc"
>   will print an entry for a directory called *./src/misc* (if one exists).  To  ignore  a
>   whole  directory  tree,  use  -prune  rather than checking every file in the tree.  For
>   example, to skip the directory *src/emacs* and all files and directories under it,  and
>   print the names of the other files found, do something like this:
>
> `find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print`

From [Findutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html)

> -- Action: -exec command ;
>        This insecure variant of the *-execdir* action is specified by
>        POSIX.  The main difference is that the command is executed in the
>        directory from which *find* was invoked, meaning that *{}* is
>        expanded to a relative path starting with the name of one of the
>        starting directories, rather than just the basename of the matched
>        file.
>
> While some implementations of *find* replace the *{}* only where
>    it appears on its own in an argument, GNU *find* replaces *{}*
>    wherever it appears.

And

> For example, to compare each C header file in or below the current
>        directory with the file /tmp/master:
>
> ```
>       find . -name '*.h' -execdir diff -u '{}' /tmp/master ';'
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find: prune does not ignore specified path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109900/find-prune-does-not-ignore-specified-path)

Comment: I think if anything it's a duplicate of _find-path explained_ even if the answer at _find:prune does not ignore specified path_ has an answer that seems to apply to this question. Maybe the _find-path explained_ answers make sense to someone more experienced with scripting, but they don't help me. The answers present here make more sense to me so far, even though I'm just starting to look into them.

Comment: there is much to read & learn about `find ... -prune`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Comment: Linking to the questions [@flerb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/u/235424) [references](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/376075#comment669160_376075) so I don’t have to look them up next time I’m here: *[\`find -path\` explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81372)*; *[find: prune does not ignore specified path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109900)*.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`-path` works exactly like `-name`, but applies the pattern to the entire pathname of the file being examined, instead of to the last component.

`-prune` forbids descending below the found file, in case it was a directory.

Putting it all together, the command

```
find $HOME -path $HOME/$dir_name -prune -o -name "*$file_suffix" -exec cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/ \;
```

1. Starts looking for files in `$HOME`.
2. If it finds a file matching `$HOME/$dir_name` it won't go below it ("prunes" the subdirectory).
3. Otherwise (`-o`) if it finds a file matching `*$file_suffix` copies it into `$HOME/$dir_name/`.

The idea seems to be make a backup of some of the contents of `$HOME` in a subdirectory of `$HOME`. The parts with `-prune` is obviously necessary in order to avoid making backups of backups...

Comment: If I understand then: find will iterate through each and every directory in $HOME that it has permissions to go into, except $HOME/$dir_name, which it will not descend into (because the prune action will evaluate to true and the or will not be taken), searching for files that end with $file_suffix. Then as soon as it finds one, it will execute cp "found_file.sh" into $HOME/$dir_name ?

Also, -path allows for a path to a file, and is useful when you want find to descend into directories and not just work in the current directory?

Comment: Your understanding is _almost_ correct. `-path` works just as `-name`: it selects files. The difference is that `-name` matches a pattern to the file name, whereas `-path` matches a pattern to the full pathname. `find` always descends into subdirectories, unless prevented by `-maxdepth` or `-prune` etc.

Comment: Oh! -path is being applied to $HOME/$dir_name -prune then, it's the order of commands that was messing me up, and -path is necessary for the prune command because it needs to match the full path of the pruned directory.

Comment: @Darren I'm not sure if that's quite accurate. `-path $HOME/$dir_name` is one action. It is a test that checks whether the path of the current file being examined matches whatever `$HOME/$dir_name` is. `-prune` is a separate action. I think the _first_ sentence of your first comment accurately reflects how that works.

Comment: Would it be missing something to see it as a pipe? I swapped -prune with -print and think the flow is clear now : find $HOME | -path $HOME/$dir_name | -print

Comment: @Darren: It is **not** equivalent to a pipe. I think you are misunderstanding how `find` works. Essentially, it walks the subtree given as an argument; for each file it finds it evaluates the given expression, stopping when the expression is known to be true or false. By default it walks all the tree, but `-maxdepth` and `-prune` can prevent it from descending further. `-path` <pattern> is a predicate; it evaluates to true if the full pathname of the current file being considered matches the pattern, and to false otherwise. The implicit connector is "and".

Comment: I see this now by using find $PATH -print and am see how to use -print as a tool to investigate what's happening

Comment: should the -o really be there. it means or. no? i am finding with -o they are still being parsed.

Comment: @momomo: I don't understand. What is being parsed? And yes, the `-o` must definitely be there, because the default connector is "and", and we don't want that.

Comment: if you are oring and you wish to exclude the path which is what prune is for .. then you are doing nothing really. you can not exclude and then or ... exclude and ...

Comment: @momomo: I'm afraid that you are confused about how `-o` and the implicit `-a` connectors work. Hint: they short-circuit. `-o` will stop evaluating the find expression as soon as it finds its left operand true; that it, if the `-prune` is executed then the evaluation stops; which means that the `-name` ... `-exec` part is evaluated only if the `-prune` was *not* executed yet.

Comment: I was not getting that when I ran the command. The directory pruned was till being searched. But who knows, maybe I made a mistake. You seem sure.

Comment: That was a brilliant, simple, accurate explanation.  Thank you.  I feel like I just woke up, and now I know kung fu.  Every other time I looked at a description of prune, I felt like I was drudging through a class at Tiger Schulman's Karate (which is not where you might expect to learn kung fu).

Answer (score 8):

It is part of the find command, the -exec statement.

It allows you to interact with the file/directory found by the `find` command.

`find $HOME -path $HOME/$dir_name -prune -o -name "*$file_suffix" -exec cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/ \;`

`find $HOME`  means find files/directories in $HOME

To understand `-path <some_path>`, see [`find -path` explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81372/find-path-explained)

To understand `-prune`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

`-o` means OR, so `-path <some_path>` OR `-name *$file_suffix`

`-exec` means execute the command.

`cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/`  copy any files matching to `$HOME/$dir_name/`

`\;` means terminate the `-exec` command

Comment: Good idea to quote `‘{}'` to prevent word-splitting if the filename contains whitespace and avoid race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files (see `main 1 find`).