# Remove paths from list if parent directory is also in the list

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

My title may be a bit oddly worded, so here's my situation: I have a bunch of directory paths, e.g.

```
/a/b
/a/b/c
/a/b/c/d
/a/e/f/g/h
/a/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l
/a/e/f/g/m/n/o
/a/e/f/g/m/n/p
```

and I want to filter out all lines that are child paths of an entry that already exists in the list, e.g.

```
/a/b
/a/e/f/g/h
/a/e/f/g/m/n/o
/a/e/f/g/m/n/p
```

The directory paths are obtained from `find`, <strike>so they should reliably be in top-down order.</strike> Solutions for parsing as an array or multi-line string are both welcome.

Comment: 1. find output varies according to creation order, not alpha sort. pipe to sort if you want sorted (see [find command default sorting order](https://serverfault.com/questions/181787/find-command-default-sorting-order) .  2.   what min depth is relevant?  they're all children of `/a`, so all except `/a` should be deleted?

Comment: @cas Editted to strike out the bit about assumed order. The first codeblock is the example input, the second codeblock is the example desired output.

Comment: @cas The criteria is that they are to be removed if they are "child paths of an entry that already exists in the list," `/a/b` is in the list and is the parent directory of `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/c/d`, so `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/c/d` are to be removed. Already have  an accepted answer, though, so feel free to move on to another post. Thanks for trying to help, though, and sorry if my question wasn't sufficiently clear.

Comment: Can you use find's `-prune` arg to not have this problem in the first place?  (It can be a bit tricky to put it in the right place to trigger on the conditions you want.)

Comment: Are you just trying to find files, then, find has -type f for that.... (it's not clear from the question).

Comment: @PeterCordes wow, I was not aware of that option. That does seem to do what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short *awk* solution:

```
<infile sort -u |awk 'NR==1 || index($0, pre"/")!=1{print; pre=$0}'
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming that the list of pathnames may possibly not be sorted, and that the resulting list of pathnames should be in the same order as in the input. I also assume that no pathname contains embedded newline characters.

Using `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set --
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
        for p do
                case $pathname in ("$p"/*) continue 2 ;; esac
        done

        set -- "$@" "$pathname"
done <list

printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

This reads the pathnames from the file `list`, one line at a time.  The accepted pathnames (initially an empty list) are tested against each read pathname, one at a time in the inner loop.  If an accepted pathname is a directory path prefix to the current pathname, the current pathname is discarded (the inner loop skips to the next iteration of the outer loop using `continue 2`).  If no accepted pathname is found to be a directory path prefix to the current pathname, the current pathname is accepted.

The list of accepted pathnames is kept in the positional parameters.

The `bash` shell would obviously be able to run the above script, but if you want something written specifically for that shell, you could say

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

accepted=()
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
        for p in "${accepted[@]}"; do
                [[ $pathname == "$p"/* ]] && continue 2
        done

        accepted+=("$pathname")
done <list

printf '%s\n' "${accepted[@]}"
```

---

Using `awk` with the identical approach as above:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) if (index($0, accepted[i] "/") == 1) next; accepted[++n]=$0 } END { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print accepted[i] }' list
/a/b
/a/e/f/g/h
/a/e/f/g/m/n/o
/a/e/f/g/m/n/p
```

The `awk` code, nicified:

```c
{
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                if (index($0, accepted[i] "/") == 1)
                        next

        accepted[++n] = $0
}

END {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                print accepted[i]
}
```

You should be able to see the obvious similarities between this `awk` program and the shell code variations at the start.

This uses `index()` to test whether an accepted pathname is the prefix to the current pathname.  You could have used `if ($0 ~ "^" acceped[i] "/")` instead, but a shortcoming of this is that the pathnames themselves are used as part of the regular expression.  This starts to matter once you have pathnames containing characters like `.` and `*` etc.

Comment: +1 for the awk version.  i'll hold my nose and ignore the shell while read loops.

Answer (score 8):

If I'm not mistaken, a list of normalized(*), or at least consistently presented paths, sorted with the usual lexicographic sort, has subdirectories of a directory appear immediately after that directory (recursively). Hence, it should be enough to look only at the previous (non-dropped) line.

<sub>(* By normalized, I mean `/foo/bar` or `/foo/bar/`, and not e.g.
`/foo/asdf/../bar` or `/foo///bar//`. The output from `find` would not be a problem since while it does give non-normalized output if given a non-normalized starting directory, the output is at least consistent.)</sub>

A path can still be a prefix of another while being only a sibling but not a parent, e.g. `/foo` and `/foobar`. To deal with such cases, we can add a trailing slash to each line that doesn't already have one.

Hence (with `/foo` and `/foobar` added to the test, and no attempt at golfing the code):

```
$ sort paths.txt | awk '! /\/$/ { $0 = $0 "/" } 
                        last && last == substr($0, 1, length(last)) { next; } 
                        { last = $0; sub(/\/$/, "", $0); print }' 
/a/b
/a/e/f/g/h
/a/e/f/g/m/n/o
/a/e/f/g/m/n/p
/foo
/foobar
```

The first line adds the slash to the current line `$0` if needed; the second compares the line to the last stored one (in `last`) if there is one, and drops matching lines; the third stores and prints any undropped lines, with the trailing slash removed. (Remove the `sub(...)` to keep them.)

Comment: +1. Normalising the paths is interesting and good practice, but it's not going to be an issue in output from `find`.  Matching only the previous line on sorted input is a clever optimisation - much faster and uses much less memory.

Answer (score 5):

With perl (and sort process substitution to guarantee the input is sorted):

```
$ perl -lne '
    unless (defined($paths) && m:^($paths)/:) {
      $paths{$_}++;
      $paths=join("|", map +( "\Q$_\E" ), keys %paths);
    };

    END { print join("\n", sort keys %paths) }' <(sort input.txt)
/a/b
/a/e/f/g/h
/a/e/f/g/m/n/o
/a/e/f/g/m/n/p
```

It progressively builds a regular expression matching paths it has already seen. If a path hasn't been seen before, it adds it to the `%paths` hash, which is used both to build the regular expression and to contain the list of paths that need to be printed at the end of the script.

Each path is surrounded by \Q and \E when added to the regular expression, to make sure that any `perlre` meta-characters (like `.`, `?`, `*`, etc) are disabled.

Comment: There's an issue with using the pathnames as part of the regular expression. Try with a modified input where the first line is `/a/.*` (a hidden file named `.*` in the directory `/a`), or `/a/[eb]`.  You can fix this by using `index()` instead. See my `awk` code.

Comment: the list contains directories only...although i guess a directory could be called '/a/.*'.   Easily fixed with \Q and \E to escape all meta-characters.

Comment: Ah, yes. That works too.

Comment: @cas, note that there's the corner case of e.g. `/foo` and `/foobar`, where one is a prefix of another, but _not_ a parent. I think that could be dealt with by adding trailing slashes or so, but you may want to check.

Comment: @ilkkachu i thought about adding a trailing slash to the RE when i wrote the answer, but wasn't sure if it would introduce problems in a larger input data set.  i'll do some testing.

Answer (score 2):

**GNU sed** with extended regex mode `-E`. The previous line with no subsets is stored in hold space.

```
< file sort \
| sed -En '
    G
    /^([^\n]+)\/.*\n\1$/d
    s/\n.*//p;h
'
```

---

```
< file sort \
| perl -lne '
    $prev //= $_;
    print($prev = $_)
       if index($_, "$prev/");
'
```

---

**POSIX sed**  does not allow `[^\n]` so we rewrite in POSIX compliant constructs

```
< file sort \
| sed -e '
    H;x
    \|^\(..*\)\n\1/|{
      s/\n.*//;h;d
    }
    g
'
```

Answer (score 2):

**For a list of files from `find`**, you *may* be able to use **`find ... -prune`** to avoid the problem in the first place: exclude descending into children of the current path, if it's a directory itself.  [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/376075/explain-finds-path-and-prune-options) shows an example, and see the man page.  If trying to combine it with `-o` on the OR of some other conditions, you may want `find ... \( -name 'foo*' -o -name 'bar*' \) -prune`.

**There are other cases where it's not going to do what you need, so you will need one of the other answers that process the output of `find`.**

e.g. if you're using `find -name marker.txt -printf '%h\n'` to find directories that happen to contain a `marker.txt`, you can't `-prune` on that because `-name` only matches a file within the directory, not the directory itself.

Or for other future readers whose list of files *isn't* straight from `find` in the first place.